# Error loading project after Android Studio 2.3 updates

Tags: java, android, android-studio, project

Today I updated my Android studio to new version 2.3 and when I try to load my project popup with following error. Please help me out as I am working on some important project.

thank you
[image]

Comment: did u try closing android studio and opening it again?

Comment: @Aditya Yes, I even try after restarting my Macbook.

Comment: Check the sdk manager for any pending updates

Comment: @Vishrut Updated pending items but still the same annoying popup

Comment: Try invalid/restart option. it will remove old caches of as.

Comment: @androidnoobdev As I am on Android studio welcome screen, not able to find your valuable suggested option.

Comment: try reinstalling the android studio

Comment: @UserSharma Download and reinstalled Android Studio 2.3. Unluckily it doesn't work!!! Same error popup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem but with different plugin (BlackBerry OS AVD caused this problem). I searched for plugins name (last line in your error message), it showed BB dev site, I immediately knew what was going on.

Find which plugin caused error, then go to Configrue (bottom right corner) -> Plugins -> delete your plugin, restart android studio.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, some plugins were creating problem for me. so delete the plugins and restart the android studio.